# Login not Allowed in Force.com Sites

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, force.com

I am trying to enable the Login for the site, but i can't see the option to enable it.
i am having following screen when i click on login settings button from sites detail page.
How to enable Login for site?
[image: Login not Allowed]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Login will become available only when Login Enabled box is ticked for your portal.You may need to attach a portal for achieving authentication through website.

Have a look at one awesome doc from wiki.developer.force

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites

Comment: The Customer Portal and the Partner Portal can be thought of as the authentication providers for a Site. In order to log in to a Site, it needs to be associated with a Portal which is Login Enabled.